# Need cycling route options from Bangkok to Siem Reap (via Poi Pet)

Tags: thailand, bicycles, cambodia, bangkok, siem-reap

I am planning a cycle trip from Bangkok to Angkor Vat next week crossing the border at Aranyaprathet/Poi Pet.  I need some help in choosing the route to take, and my preference would be to take a scenic route which is not too traffic congested or dangerous for cyclists.

Below are the specific questions:

1. How is the Ayutthaya to Aranyaprathet direct route (via Prachin Buri
   and Kabin Buri) for cycling?  Is it industrial and congested (as
   someone said to me)?  Or is it fairly decent for cycling?
2. If the Ayutthaya - Aranyaprathet route is not too good for cycling, then can someone help me choose between the two options below:

   a) Head north-east from Ayutthaya to Pak Chong and Pak Thong Chai, and then cut southwards on AH19 to Kabin Buri, and then continue on AH1 till Poi Pet.

   b) Head north-east from Ayutthaya to Pak Chong and and then to Nang Rong before moving southwards to Aranyaprathet on AH121 along the border with Cambodia.

The criteria would be:  scenic route, safe for cycling, and added bonus would be temples on the way.  While I want to avoid traffic, I also would not want to take very isolated roads as I am riding solo and know only English.

Comment: Try http://www.thaivisa.com/forum/? Someone there has probably done what you are aiming for.

Comment: Definitely need to split this into separate questions, as per the [faq].